# Cancelling a BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, backgroundworker

My `DoWork` for `backgroundworker1` sets a wait timer via a class `WakeUp`, it works well.

The problem right now is that sometimes my `while CancellationPending` is ending in an infinite loop. So inside `DoWork` there is a call to `WaitOne`, the `DoWork` sets the wait timer stuff and waits the thread until the timer triggers.

I need for the `BackgroundWorker` to shut down right away but as well I have to keep a reference to `BackgroundWorker` so I can keep track of each alarm in my program. Why is `CancellationPending` taking so long? It never seems to finish. Is there some way to kill off the `backgroundworker` without having to wait like this in a while loop for so long?

```
switch (alarmNum)
{
    case 1:
                WakeUp.CancelWakeUp(threadHandles[removal]);
        if(backgroundworker1.IsBusy)
        {

            backgroundworker1.CancelAsync();
        }

        while(backgroundworker1.CancellationPending)
        {

        }

        backgroundworker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        break;
    case 2:
        if (backgroundworker2.IsBusy)
        {
            backgroundworker2.CancelAsync();
        }
        backgroundworker2.RunWorkerAsync();
        break;
    case 3:
        if (backgroundworker3.IsBusy)
        {
            backgroundworker3.CancelAsync();
        }
        backgroundworker3.RunWorkerAsync();
        break;
    case 4:
        if (backgroundworker4.IsBusy)
        {
            backgroundworker4.CancelAsync();
        }
        backgroundworker4.RunWorkerAsync();
        break;
    case 5:
        if (backgroundworker5.IsBusy)
        {
            backgroundworker5.CancelAsync();
        }
        backgroundworker5.RunWorkerAsync();
        break;
}



    private void bw1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;


        if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
        {
          e.Cancel = true;
        }

        WakeUp temp = new WakeUp("spalarm1");
        threadHandles[0] = temp.tHandle;
        temp.initWakeUp(dtCurSpan);

        //****************************
              It's blocking here -< <--
              temp.DoWork sets a system timer so its blocking
              with a call to WaitOne inside WakeUp. The timer I'm setting
              is called a waitable timer so its blocking since the system is
              waiting for it to expire so the thread can end
           *******************************/
        temp.DoWork();
    }
```

WakeUp.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    class WakeUp
    {
        public delegate void TimerCompleteDelegate(IntPtr complretionArg,
                                               UInt32 timerLow, UInt32 timerHigh);

        public SafeWaitHandle tHandle;
        bool rslt;

        //Various imports of kernel32.dll so the waitable timer can be set
        //on the system
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern SafeWaitHandle CreateWaitableTimer(IntPtr lpTimerAttributes, bool bManualReset, string lpTimerName);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool SetWaitableTimer(SafeWaitHandle hTimer, [In] ref long pDueTime, int lPeriod, IntPtr pfnCompletionRoutine, IntPtr lpArgToCompletionRoutine, bool fResume);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool CancelWaitableTimer(SafeWaitHandle hTimer);

        //SafeHandle.DangerousGetHandle Method
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

        //The constructor will use a TimeSpan to set a waitable timer
        public WakeUp(string wtName)
        {
            tHandle = CreateWaitableTimer(IntPtr.Zero, true, wtName);
        }

        public int initWakeUp(TimeSpan smParam)
        {
            //The number of ticks needs to be negated to set a waitable timer in this fashion
            long waketicks = -smParam.Ticks;
            rslt = SetWaitableTimer(tHandle, ref waketicks, 0, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, true);

            if(!rslt)
            {
                return Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }

        private static Exception GetWin32Exception()
        {
            return Marshal.GetExceptionForHR(Marshal.GetHRForLastWin32Error());
        }

        public int DoWork()
        {
            using (EventWaitHandle wh = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset))
            {
                wh.SafeWaitHandle = tHandle;
                wh.WaitOne();
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }

            return 0;
        }



        //This function needs to check the return value of
        //CancelWaitableTimer
        static public void CancelWakeUp(SafeWaitHandle clHandle)
        {
            CancelWaitableTimer(clHandle);
        }
    }
}
```

Possible solution:

```
case 1:
WakeUp.CancelWakeUp(threadHandles[removal]);

threadHandles[removal] = null;
backgroundworker1.CancelAsync();
backgroundworker1.Dispose();

backgroundworker1 = new BackgroundWorker();
backgroundworker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
backgroundworker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
backgroundworker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw1_DoWork);
backgroundworker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bw1_ProgressChanged);
backgroundworker1.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw1_RunWorkerCompleted);

backgroundworker1.RunWorkerAsync();
break;
```

but I was trying to avoid this type of code.

Comment: Show the code where the BackgroundWorker cancels.  If you want BackgroundWorker to cancel fast then check fast.

Comment: How am I supposed to check when DoWork is blocking?

Comment: You are calling the timer that calls cancels background worker in the  background worker in a blocking manner and then calling another dowork?

Comment: I'm starting to see the picture. The first thing I'm doing is cancel the timer so it is supposed to stop blocking.

Comment: *It never seems to finish* - that's because it doesn't know when to break out early. `BackgroundWorker` cancellation isn't like killing a process - you have to code the cooperative cancellation (presumably inside your `WakeUp.DoWork` method). My guess is you're not doing it based on the fact that you're not passing in the worker reference to `WakeUp.DoWork`, so it will run until completion regardless of the cancellation flag.

Comment: So my check for cancellation must not be right then? I tried moving that block to the end of the backgroundworker1's DoWork.

Comment: Your check for cancellation is useless - simple as that. Performing it at the start of `bw1_DoWork` accomplishes nothing as the worker is unlikely to be cancelled at that point. Performing it at the end is also no good because it happens *after* `temp.DoWork()` (which, as you said, is blocking) has completed.

Comment: What can be done? I have to be able to kill one these off pretty much on demand?

Comment: You'll need to post your full `WakeUp` code so that we can see how cancellation can be wired into it, and also specify which version of .NET you are targeting (so that we know which tools are available).

Comment: Eh, found your problem with the infinite loop. Calling `CancelWaitableTimer` does pretty much exactly what the name suggests, so your call to `wh.WaitOne()` ends up blocking forever because the handle is never signaled by the timer. You just need to expose your `EventWaitHandle` publically and `Set` it yourself when you want the cancellation to occur (i.e. when you call `BackgroundWorker.Cancel`) so that `wh.WaitOne()` unblocks and `temp.DoWork` runs to completion. Sorry I lead you down a long and winding road with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with the kernel32 APIs that you're PInvoking, so I'll give you a basic example using `System.Threading.Timer` (which can be reset after a callback has been scheduled).

**EDIT**

*Changed timer logic to suppress timer callback on cancellation in order to bring the example closer to your scenario.*

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;

void BackgroundWorkerTimerCancellation()
{
    var worker = new BackgroundWorker { WorkerSupportsCancellation = true };

    // Cancellation support.
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var cancellationToken = cts.Token;

    // Cancel worker when the CancellationTokenSource is canceled.
    cancellationToken.Register(worker.CancelAsync);

    // This ManualResetEvent will allow us
    // to block until DoWork has finished
    // (testing purposes only).
    using (var outerMRE = new ManualResetEvent(false))
    {
        worker.DoWork += delegate
        {
            try
            {
                // Mimics your EventWaitHandle.
                using (var innerMRE = new ManualResetEvent(false))
                {
                    // Our timer which takes a looong time.
                    using (var timer = new Timer(_ => innerMRE.Set(), null, 10000 /* 10 seconds */, Timeout.Infinite))
                    {
                        // Wire cancellation.
                        cancellationToken.Register(() =>
                        {
                            // Cancel the timer (callback will never execute).
                            timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);

                            // Signal wait handle immediately when canceled.
                            // It's lack of this call which is making
                            // your BackgroundWorker run indefinitely
                            // when the timer is canceled.
                            innerMRE.Set();
                        });

                        // Block until timer callback runs or until
                        // the CancellationTokenSource is canceled.
                        innerMRE.WaitOne();
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                // Allow the outerMRE.WaitOne() call to complete.
                outerMRE.Set();
            }
        };

        // Start the worker (non-blocking).
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();

        // Schedule auto-cancellation after 1 second (non-blocking).
        cts.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

        // Block until DoWork has finished.
        // Will take 10 seconds without cancellation,
        // or one second with cancellation.
        outerMRE.WaitOne();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It may take me a bit to digest what you are showing me.

Comment: The essence of it is that you need a way to call `worker.CancelAsync` and also `WakeUp.CancelWakeUp` (and possibly signal your `tHandle`) *together, at the same time* in order for the cancellation to happen right there and then. I am achieving that by registering cancellation callbacks on the `CancellationToken` (and then cancelling the `CancellationTokenSource` rather than just the `BackgroundWorker`), but it doesn't mean you have to - signaling the wait handle is also a feasible option, but you'll have to find a way to pass it around.

Comment: @user2209542, Have a play with this and edit the question with the latest version of the code if you're having trouble integrating any of the concepts I have discussed. I would really like to see this through (and possibly propose a better overall solution because using wait handles in .NET 4.5 just *doesn't feel right*).