# Waiting for and terminating a thread after a given time without blocking in .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-3.5

I have a WinForms application on .NET 3.5. In this form, the user triggers an operation which is executed in another thread (a `BackgroundWorker` to be precise) so as to not block the UI thread. I'm in MVP, so all this is being done by a presenter which interacts with an interface to the view (implemented by the Windows Form). So far so good.

I would like to introduce functionality whereby a timeout period is introduced for the background operation to complete before cancelling it. Sounds simple enough. But the background operation calls a single function on a third-party component  which may never return, so the cancellation capabilities of the `BackgroundWorker` are of no use to me here. Also, the `BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted` allowed me to get back on the UI thread, so I need to wait for the timeout or success and be able to get back to my calling thread (namely the UI thread).

I tried this using a plain old `Thread` (which does support `Abort()`) and a Timer running on a second thread, but can't seem to get it to work quite right since `Join()` is blocking my UI thread despite the description stating that it will block *"[while continuing to perform standard COM and SendMessage pumping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.join%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)"*. Admittedly I assumed this implied that it would continue to process Windows Messages, which was not the case.

```
int timeoutInMsec = 10000;
Thread connectThread = new Thread(Connect);
Thread timerThread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        var timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer() { Interval = timeoutInMsec };
        timer.Tick += (_s, _e) => 
            {
                timer.Stop();
                if (connectThread.ThreadState == ThreadState.Running)
                    connectThread.Abort();
            };
    };

connectThread.Start();
timerThread.Start();
timerThread.Join();
connectThread.Join();
```

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31160697/how-to-wait-for-thread-to-complete-without-blocking-ui), I tried removing the second timer thread and adding a `ManualResetEvent` and calling `Set()` when the timer ticked, or when the Connect method did indeed complete. Here, instead of `Join` I used `WaitOne`, but unfortunately this also blocks my UI thread. I also found [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24481879/cancelling-a-backgroundworker), which a `CancellationTokenSource` which unfortunately is not available in .NET 3.5.

So, how can I spin my worker up and be able to terminate it after a given amount of time in .NET 3.5, while at the same time be able to get back to the thread where I spun up the worker thread to execute a sort of `OnCompleted` handler?

Many thanks in advance!

PS: I don't have a lot of experience in multi-threaded programming in .NET, so I'm sorry if this is trivial.

Comment: You should never ever call `Thread.Abort()` as it can corrupt the run-time state. The **only** exception is if you are trying to force the shutdown of your app. The only way to cleanly kill a thread without compromising your run-time is to launch a new process and run your thread there, then you can just kill the process.

Comment: @Enigmativity: The *never use* `Thread.Abort` is a similar blind argument as never use `Application.DoEvents`. They are often misused, indeed. But it does not mean you cannot use them properly. See their description, they are neither deprecated nor obsolete.

Comment: To the downvoter: be a chap and let me know how the question can be improved

Comment: @taffer - No, they are different arguments. The `Thread.Abort()` argument is that you can corrupt the state of the run-time - that's very bad. `Application.DoEvents()` can merely cause re-entrancy bugs that are hard to fix, but it doesn't corrupt the run-time state. The former is far worse than the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, the following algorithm should solve your problem:

- As before, create a BackgroundWorker to do your background work.
- In BackgroundWorker_DoWork,

  - create a new thread (let's call it the "third-party thread") to call your third-party library, and then
  - wait for the third-party thread to finish or the timeout to elapse. (*)

That way, your UI won't block, since *only the Backgroundworker thread* is waiting, not the main thread.

Now about the interesting part: How do you wait for the third-party thread to finish (the step marked with (*))?

My suggestion would be to simply use "loop waiting with sleep", i.e. (pseudo-code, you can use the `Stopwatch` class for the timeout):

```
do until (third-party thread has finished or x seconds have elapsed):
    Thread.Sleep for 100ms

if third-party thread has not finished:
    Abort it     // we don't have another choice
else
    Process the result
```

It's not best practice, but it's simple, it gets the job done and you can always replace it with fancy cross-thread-syncronization stuff (which is non-trivial to get right) once you got it all working.

Comment: Duh. Of course I don't care if I block the worker thread... Interestingly, calling `Abort` results in the application process not exiting when closing the form...

Comment: @user5877732: Be sure to set `IsBackground` to true, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/2689000/87698

Answer (score -1):

It's useless to create a `Forms.Timer` on a non-gui thread. Don't create it on a separate thread. Why are you `Joining` the threads? The usage of `Join` is to block the current thread until the other thread is finished.

This is untested pseudo code, this is for example purpose.

```
public class Form1: Form1
{
    private int timeoutInMsec = 10000;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Timer _timer;
    private Thread _connectThread;

    public Form1()
    {
        _connectThread = new Thread(Connect);
        _connectThread.Start();

        _timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer() { Interval = timeoutInMsec };
        _timer.Tick += (_s, _e) => 
                {
                    _timer.Stop();
                    if (_connectThread.ThreadState == ThreadState.Running)
                        _connectThread.Abort();
                };
        };
    }

    private void Connected()
    {

    }

    private void Aborted()
    {

    }

    private void Connect()
    {
        try
        {
            DoConnect3rdPartyStuff();
            this.Invoke(Connected);
        }
        catch(ThreadAbortException)
        {
            // aborted
            this.Invoke(Aborted);
        }       
    }   
}
```

Comment: I'm not in a `Form` but rather in a presenter coded against a view interface, so don't have access to the form's `Invoke` method

Comment: I used the Invoke to synchronize the call, i'm not familiar with `view interface`. You might use something that is equivalent.

Comment: It simply means that I don't have a reference to an object of type `Windows.Forms.Form` but rather an interface to a generic "view" which exposes only the necessary parts to the presenter so as to decouple the application from the technology (WinForms in this case). I was hoping for something a bit more elegant which wouldn't require every view to expose an `Invoke` method...

Comment: You could solve the synchronization within the `Connected()` method instead of the thread method. The synchronization is only needed when touching the controls etc.

Comment: Not without a way to get the UI thread in `Connected`, no. The `BackgroundWorker.RunCompleted` did exactly that for me, namely being able to run the callback on the calling thread (the UI thread)

Comment: The BackgroundWorker uses the SynchronizationContex, so uses the same technique as Invoke. So one way or another. You could use a queue and a timer to synchronize, but thats ugly.